# kotlin syntax for extending a class and implementing an interface

Tags: kotlin

I want to extend the class fragment and implement an interface with it in kotlin:

The equivalent in Java would be:

```
class LockFragment extends  Fragment implements IOnBackPressed
```

But I cannot find the syntax to define that in kotlin.

From what I've searched it looks like syntax is the same for inheritence and interface implementation in kotlin, but this does not work:

```
class LockFragment : Fragment() : IOnBackPressed
```

So which would be the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class LockFragment : Fragment(), IOnBackPressed
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class LockFragment : Fragment(), IOnBackPressed
```

see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-rules